# Typescript Strict Mode: having error on BehaviouralSubject (null)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to follow the documentation on dynamic query from the `AngularFireStore` documentation,
[here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md)
I'm just starting and upon typing the behaviourSubject on my constructor.

I know this is just a typescript rule matter, but I am new and also confused what's wrong here. Disabling strict mode does it but I don't want to do that.

```
export class MembersSequencingComponent implements OnInit {
    customers$ : Observable<Customer[]>; // instead of using an interface I've used a model
    zoneFilters$: BehaviorSubject<Customer|null>;

constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
    
    this.zoneFilters$ = new BehaviorSubject(null); >> //typescript error happens here


   }

 
}
```

[image]

However, my typescript is giving me an error.

```
Type 'BehaviorSubject<null>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<Customer | null>'.
  Types of property 'observers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observer<null>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<Customer | null>[]'.
      Type 'Observer<null>' is not assignable to type 'Observer<Customer | null>'.
        Type 'Customer | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
          Type 'Customer' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)
```

Customer Model

```
export class Customer {
    customerNo: string;
    customerAccountNo: string;
    customerName: string;
}
```

Comment: use the generic `BehaviorSubject<T>`, something like `this.zoneFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject<Customer | null>(null);` .  The generic form will allow you to properly type the `BehaviorSubject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provide a generic parameter to tell typescript that the type used by the class may be either null or Customer. Try the following

```
  constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.zoneFilters$ = new BehaviorSubject<Customer | null>(null);
  }
```